# How to Match Dynamic Url with Static Url using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to know how to match a dynamic URL to a static URL using htaccess. My code is the following:-

My php function :-

```
public static function  ToTagLinks($tags, $page = 1){
   $tags = explode(',', $tags); 
   foreach ($tags as &$tag) {
//$link ='tagged/'.self::CleanUrlText($tag);
      $link ='index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName='.self::CleanUrlText($tag) ;
      if($page > 1)
         $link .='&Page='.$page;
         $tag = '<a class="taglist" href="'.self::Build($link).
                          '" title="show post tagged ' . $tag . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
   }
   return  implode(', ', $tags);            
}
```

My htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# Specify the folder in which the application resides.
# Use / if the application is in the root.
RewriteBase /rswebtek_blog

# Rewrite to correct domain to avoid canonicalization problems
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite URLs ending in /index.php or /index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite category pages
RewriteRule ^.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?CategoryId=$1&Page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?CategoryId=$1 [L]

#Redirect search results
RewriteRule ^search-results/find-(.*)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?SearchResults&SearchString=$1&Page=$2[L]
RewriteRule ^search-results/find-?(.*)//?$ index.php?SearchResults&SearchString=$1&Page=1 [L]

#Redirect  tag search results
RewriteRule ^tagged/(.*)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName=$1&Page=$2[L]
RewriteRule ^tagged/?(.*)//?$ index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName=$1&Page=1 [L]

# Rewrite subpages of the home page
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L]

# Rewrite Post details pages
RewriteRule ^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?PostId=$1 [L]
</IfModule> 
# Set the default 500 page for Apache errors
ErrorDocument 500 /rswebtek_blog/500.php

#Set the defualt 404 error page
ErrorDocument 404 /rswebtek_blog/404.php
```

my other links work properly but this code for tag search link not work properly 404.php error occur but if I used dynamic url its work good.

Comment: Anubhava Ji in My above link function I want to add just this type of link    wwww.example.com/tagged/php but my dynamic url is index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName=php

Comment: Anubhava I have edited my above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try those 2 rules as:

```
#Redirect  tag search results
RewriteRule ^tagged/([^/]+)/page-(\d+)/?$ index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName=$1&Page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tagged/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName=$1&Page=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanking you very much Code works good. Will you please what is the problem in my codes?

Comment: It is a regex problem. You were using `.*` and `//` in your regex pattern.